# 404 Error while deploying Android App Engine Project on Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, deployment, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-endpoints

I've created a simple android application with Google Cloud Module in it. I use Android Studio as IDE.

Everything was Ok when I ran it using localhost. Before that I`d registered app in Google Developers Console and received

Project ID: api-project-533338873956 Project Number: 533338873956

Than I wanted to deploy my backend module to server and troubles occurred.
Firstly, I used terminal to deploy app through command line

> gradle backend:appengineUpdate

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>api-project-533338873956</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.google.finalapp.backend.MyEndpoint,
                com.google.finalapp.backend.QuoteEndpoint</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

But when I came through initialization I caught an error 404

> Jul 03, 2015 11:19:46 AM
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader
>   readAppEngineWebXml INFO: Successfully processed
>   /home/Final/backend/build/exploded-app/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
>   Jul 03, 2015 11:19:46 AM
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader
>   readConfigXml INFO: Successfully processed
>   /home/Final/backend/build/exploded-app/WEB-INF/web.xml
>
> Beginning interaction for module default... Jul 03, 2015 11:19:47 AM
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
>   WARNING: Error posting to URL:
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=api-project-533338873956&version=1&
>   404 Not Found This application does not exist
>   (app_id=u'api-project-533338873956').

The fact is the application is registered in Console and I can enter to it with my credentials.

Any idea what is wrong with my sample? And why application does not exist (app_id=u'api-project-533338873956')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the right user is being used during the gradle appengine deploy?

You may also want to try doing this from Android Studio directly https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/app_engine/run_test_deploy#deploying_backends

Comment: Yes, there is trouble with log in. When I make deploy through Android Studio I catch error "You must be logged in to perform this action". Hmm, but where should I log in in Android Studio?

Comment: I used "Add account" button (but I suggected that I've already signed in in browser) and everything is Ok. Thanks!